# How to get structured json from two tables using REST request

Tags: json, rest, android-json, dreamfactory

Is it capable to implement feature of procedure on getting structured response from two tables

I have two tables: 'Company' and 'Phone'

Company contains companies and Phone contains phone numbers on each company.
One company --> many phones related by companyID

I need exactly this structure:

```
{
  "resource": [
    {
      "companyId": 1,
      "companyName": "Apple",
      "companySubject": "Security",
      "phones": [
        {
          "name": "tel1",
          "phone": "+178548555"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "companyId": 2,
      "companyName": "Samsung",
      "companySubject": "IT",
      "phones": [
        {
          "name": "tel1",
          "phone": "+178548555"
        },
        {
          "name": "tel2",
          "phone": "+178548555"
        },
        {
          "name": "tel3",
          "phone": "+178548555"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "companyId": 3,
      "companyName": "LG",
      "companySubject": "Accounting",
      "phones": [
        {
          "name": "tel1",
          "phone": "+178548555"
        },
        {
          "name": "tel2",
          "phone": "+178548555"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Problem is that they are in separate tables and I cant figure out how to implement it.

I use dreamfactory for backend

Answer (score 1):

If the tables have a foreign key relationship (defined in the database) then you can simply fetch the phones by calling GET `{service_name}/_table/{table_name}?related={relationship_name}`
In your example above this might be something like GET `my_service/_table/Company?related=phones_by_companyId`
You can get the relationship name by looking at the table structure information in the DreamFactory Schema tab, and you can even create an alias for this relationship so that the relationship name would just be `phones`. [Working with related data](http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Features/Database/Related_Data)

If the tables are not related you can use DreamFactory's virtual foreign keys to relate them. More info about VFK's can be found [on the wiki](http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Tutorials/Using_virtual_foreign_keys)